# Can you please explain how Manger's attack against RSA OAEP works?

Tags: rsa, attack, oaep

I searched but found nothing except [the original paper](http://archiv.infsec.ethz.ch/education/fs08/secsem/Manger01.pdf), and I can't wrap my head around it. Can you help me by giving an overview and then if possible, a short explanation of the algo?

Comment: This may help: https://research.kudelskisecurity.com/2018/04/05/breaking-rsa-oaep-with-mangers-attack/#bilbio

Comment: [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/61138/555) may help.

Answer (score 2):

### The big picture

In [RSAES-OAEP](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=16), for a public modulus $n$ of $8k-7$ to $8k$ bits, a valid ciphertext $c$ is (among many other conditions) such that $(c^d\bmod n)\,<\,2^{8k-8}$. Manger's attack assumes that adversaries can send queries to a device intended for decryption, which performs that check (as it should), and somewhat leaks if this condition is met or not; which is an implementation error: normally the device should not tell what went wrong with an invalid $c$ that it that it received (at least, when a first test that $c\in[0,n)$ passes). The leak could be by a specific error code, or by timing.

Given the public key $(n,e)$ and any $c\in[0,n)$, by sending a number of carefully crafted $x_i\ne c$ and analyzing the bits of information ${x_i}^d\bmod n\overset?<2^{k-8}$ leaking from the device, Manger's attack manages to find $m=c^d\bmod n$. If $c$ is a valid ciphertext, that can be used to decipher it. If the key is also usable for signature, that could also be used to sign.

### Details

The adversary computes and sends $x_i=c\,{s_i}^e\bmod n$ for appropriate values of $s_i$, and thus learns from the decryption device $(m\,s_i\bmod n)\overset?<2^{8k-8}$. By choosing the $s_i$ wisely, the adversary narrows down on $m$.

[I'm making this a community wiki and leave it to others to detail the steps and remove that note]. [This](https://romailler.ch/2018/04/05/manger-explained/) explains it.

Comment: In other words, it uses essentially the same logic as Bleichenbacher's attack against PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption...