# RSA PKCS#1 OAEP Padding Schema - padding 0 for first octet?

Tags: rsa, padding, oaep

In this document, it shows the EM will have one zero octet padding prefixed.

```
                     +----------+---------+-------+
                DB = |  lHash   |    PS   |   M   |
                     +----------+---------+-------+
                                    |
          +----------+              V
          |   seed   |--> MGF ---> xor
          +----------+              |
                |                   |
       +--+     V                   |
       |00|    xor <----- MGF <-----|
       +--+     |                   |
         |      |                   |
         V      V                   V
       +--+----------+----------------------------+
 EM =  |00|maskedSeed|          maskedDB          |
       +--+----------+----------------------------+
```

However, in this document, page 37, it does not have this 00 octet.

For the standard (or the implementation of openssl) RSA PKCS#1 OAEP padding, which one (with 00 octet or without octet) is the standard/correct?

In fact, I've done the following tests:

1. I use RSA_public_encrypt(RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) and find out the
   max message length is 214, which should be yielded by 256-20*2-2(k - 2hLen - 2).However, per https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/RSA_private_decrypt.html, it mentions "*EME-OAEP as defined in PKCS #1 v2.0*" so I think it should be based on rfc2437. But the max length for rfc2437 is "emLen-1-2hLen", which is a conflict?
2. I use RSA_public_encrypt(RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) to encrypt a
   message(8 bytes only) and then use
   RSA_public_decrypt(RSA_NO_PADDING) to decrypt it to see the output. I notice there always be a leading 00 octet padded. This suggests it is based on rfc3447(v2.1). I also have no idea about this.

Comment: It matters what version of PKCS1 you use because 2.0 used one notation and 2.1 and 2.2 used a different but functionally equivalent notation. In 2.0 (rfc2437) EME-OAEP-ENCODE is invoked with emLen = k-1 where k is the size of the modulus n=pq, and the 'message' is limited to emLen-2hLen-1 = k-2hLen-2 . EM is then k-1 octets, but when converted by OS2IP in step 2 of 7.1.1 it results in the 'k-size' integer equal to 00 || EM, and on decryption step 4 of 7.1.2 enforces this. Compare https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40032/why-did-oaep-change-from-pkcs1-v2-0-and-v2-1 .

Answer (score 1):

According to RFC 2437...

- RSAES-OAEP can operate on messages of length up to $k-2-2\cdot hLen$ octets, where $hLen$ is the length of the hash function output for EME-OAEP and $k$ is the length in octets of the recipient's RSA modulus.
- The padding string $\text{PS}$ in EME-PKCS1-v1_5 is at least eight octets long, which is a security condition for public-key operations that prevents an attacker from recovering data by trying all possible encryption blocks.
- 3. Generate an octet string PS consisting of $emLen-||M||-2\cdot hLen-1$ zero octets. The length of $\text{PS}$ may be $0$.
- concisely,  the length of zero padding will be $${emLen-||M||-2\cdot hLen-1}$$

Running with OpenSSL;

`openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey priv2.txt -in cipher.txt  -raw -hexdump`

and the first line of the output is;

`0000 - 00 25 2b 2c e4 b5 a8 6c-a1 d1 cc bd 0b 26 d2 9c   .%+,...l.....&..`

You can see that the first byte above is `0x00`

Comment: Quick question, why not reference the newer [RFC 8017](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017)?

Comment: Thanks SSA and DannyNiu. My confusion comes from the following: Per https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/RSA_private_decrypt.html, for the OAEP,  it states it is "EME-OAEP as defined in *PKCS #1 v2.0* with SHA-1,...". Therefore, it should be based on RFC 2437. However, when I RSA_private_encrypt(RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) and then RSA_private_decrypt(RSA_NO_PADDING), I always see a leading 00 octet is padded. Any idea?

Comment: @CHL,  Are you getting 00 with any arbitrary plaintext? Could you provide us your sample plaintext and openssl command  you use for encryption and decryption?

Comment: you will get 00 always padded at the beginning of padded string. Is that you are asking?

Comment: Yes. I always get 00 when I use RSA_private_decrypt(RSA_NO_PADDING).

Comment: Here is my testing program:
RSA_public_encrypt(*len, szIn, szEncryptedOut, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
RSA_private_decrypt(len, szEncryptedOut, szOut, rsa, RSA_NO_PADDING);
szOut[0] is always 00

Comment: yes it will be, OAEP is not a simple padding scheme. If you want to see what the OAEP padding does to the clear text, you can use the "rsautl -decrypt -raw -hexdump" command to keep whatever OAEP padding did to the clear text:   I am adding it to my Answer above.

Comment: Much appreciated, SSA. But according to RFC 2437, there should be no leading zero padding and the size is "emLen-||M||-2hLen-1" instead of "emLen-||M||-2hLen-2". Don't know why...